# How can I map the result of a MySQL query into java model class?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-boot

I am working on spring boot and Hibernate and
I need data from different table in mysql database so I ran custom query that to get data from different tables.And my query is,

```
 @Query(value = "Select i.item_id,i.item_name,s.size_name,sp.Prices from mt_item i join mt_sizeprice sp on i.item_id= sp.item_id join mt_size s on sp.size_id=s.size_id where i.merchant_fk= ?1 and is_featured=1",nativeQuery = true)
    List<Object> get(long merchantId);
```

The result of the query is,

[image]

As the data is from different table I am unable to map List of data of Object into the List of my model class as,

```
List<Object> get(long merchantId); to
List<FavoriteItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the result of your query will be List of Object[] instead of Object List. You can pass result to method and create List of FavoriteItem by iterating over results.